# How to adjust joy-ui theme spacing with HTML font-size: 10px

Tags: material-ui, joy-ui

Im trying to embed Joy-UI components into HTML page with

```
:root {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}
```

The UI looks small and unreadable.
I increased default theme with bigger fontSize and lineHeight, but it fixed only part of Typogaphy, TextBoxes and buttons are still smaller then expected

```
const theme = extendTheme({
  fontSize: {
    xl4: "3.6rem",
    xl3: "3rem",
    xl2: "2.4rem",
    xl: "2rem",
    lg: "1.8rem",
    md: "1.6rem",
    sm: "1.4rem",
    xs: "1.2rem",
  },
  lineHeight: {
    xs: "2.133344", // largest font sizes: h1, h2
    sm: "2.285728", // normal font sizes
    md: "2.4", // normal font sizes
    lg: "2.488896", // large font sizes for components
    xl: "2.666672", // smallest font sizes
  },
});
```

What else do I need to extend?
Is there a more generic approach to it?